# Запрос на стороннее апи из nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, request

Необходимо получить данные с https://forkdelta.io c помощью апи https://github.com/forkdelta/backend-replacement/tree/master/docs/api

Вот код:

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
   const io = require('socket.io-client');
   socket = io.connect('https://api.forkdelta.com', { transports: 
   ['websocket'] });

socket.on('connect', function() {
    console.log('socket connected');
    socket.emit('getMarket', {
        token: "0x6fff3806bbac52a20e0d79bc538d527f6a22c96b",
        user: "" });

});
  socket.on('market', function(payload) {
    console.log(payload.orders.buys);

    const json = JSON.stringify(payload.orders.buys);
    response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    response.end(json);
});

}).listen(3000);

console.log("Server has started.");
```

Сохраняю его в server.js и исполняю команду node server.js

клиент отдельно в index.html

```
 <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
 <script>
   var socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
   socket.on('connect', function(){});
   socket.on('market', function(data){
      console.log(data);
   });
   socket.on('disconnect', function(){});
</script>
```

Запускаю код по ссылке http://localhost:3000 с локального сервера - виснет

Запускаю код отсюда https://repl.it/repls/DeafeningBlushingAddons - успешно

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться как правильно запустить код из браузера, Далее предполагается разобрать массив данных и преобразовать в таблицу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Кратко**

Приняв запрос (от браузера, по http://localhost:3000) и сделав всё что нужно (т.е. 
 выполнив запрос к указанному API) верните браузеру ответ.

```
socket.on('market', function(payload) {
  console.log(payload.orders.buys);

  const json = JSON.stringify(payload.orders.buys);
  response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  response.end(json);
});
```

**Развёрнуто**

Сервер "виснет" потому что вы не используете аргументы, которые вы принимаете в callback функции, которую вы передаёте в метод `http.createServer`. В указанной callback-функции вы принимаете, и почему-то игнорируете, аргументы `request` и `response`. Сервер, на самом деле не "виснет", а не может дождаться, когда вы воспользуетесь вторым аргументом `response` для того, что бы вернуть ответ на запрос браузера.

Comment: vihtor, поправил код с учетом замечаний, добавил еще клиента, но не понимаю - как висело так и висит

Comment: @игорь88, у меня, при запуске вашего кода, происходит попытка подключения к `https://api.forkdelta.com`. Попытка завершается неудачей `ECONNRESET: TransportError: socket hang up`. После чего начинаются столь же безуспешные попытки переподключиться. По этому всё "висит".
Сам я не работал ни с `socket.io-client` ни с сервисом `forkdelta.com` по этому тут я вам помочь не могу. На данном этапе уберите из кода создание и запуск http-сервера и займитесь отладкой подключения через `socket.io-client`. Скорее всего проблема с SSL-сертификатом или сервис просто не доступен. Может ещё что-то.

Comment: спасибо за тест и комментарий. Вообще к этому сервису (https://forkdelta.app) к апи которого подключаюсь, необходим vpn, когда просто надо зайти на сайт (https://forkdelta.app)